# How to execute a comand in a specific directory to run in a WIndows Terminal window

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-terminal

I have been reading the docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments and I just can't figure out how to open a program in a specific location to run using wt, I have tried:

```
wt -d d:\develop\config-server start gradlew bootrun
wt d:\develop\config-server\gradlew bootrun
wt d:\develop\config-server\gradlew.exe "bootrun" (with and without quotes)
wt -d d:\develop\config-server gradlew.exe bootrun
wt -d d:\develop\config-server gradlew bootrun
```

and many variants and I always get this kind of error

```
[error 0x80070002 when launching `gradlew bootrun']
```

Comment: Use `wt -p Gradle -d "d:\develop\config-server"` after you have set the profile instance for gradle.

Comment: If this is windows 10 specific e.g. if windows terminal didn't exist before windows 10.. then you should add windows10 tag to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm correctly understanding what you are attempting, try `wt new-tab -d d:\develop\config-server d:\develop\config-server\gradlew bootrun`.  If that works, try shortening it to `wt new-tab -d d:\develop\config-server gradlew bootrun`, but I believe it's going to require the first version with fully-qualified path for the command as well.

Update -- Since neither of those worked for you, try:

`wt new-tab -d d:\develop\config-server c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c d:\develop\config-server\gradlew.exe bootrun`.

I did a few tests with various proofs, such as `wt new-tab -d c:\Windows\System32 c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir /P`.

Now if you have to throw any quotes or escaped characters in your commandline, it's a whole new story.

Also, I notice that the tab title is that of the `defaultProfile` in the Windows Terminal settings.  However, the above command does *not* run in the Default Profile.  To test this, I:

- Changed my default profile to WSL Ubuntu
- Did a `wsl --terminate Ubuntu`
- Confirmed that it was stopped with `wsl -l -v`
- Ran the above command
- Checked `wsl -l -v` while the `dir /P` was still in progress - The Ubuntu WSL instance was not running.

You can set the title if desired with:

`wt new-tab --title "Gradle" -d d:\develop\config-server d:\develop\config-server\gradlew bootrun`

Comment: that didn'work, I'm sorry, I still get the same error, the example with cmd.exe works tho, which is super weird

Comment: Bummer - That is odd that the `cmd` version works, but `gradlew` doesn't.  I also tested with some other commands, such as a `more` of a long file, and even trying `notepad.exe` to open a file.  This last one, of course, opened the file in the correct directory but closed the WT tab immediately since it's a Windows executable.

Comment: @DanielArechiga I updated the answer with a new potential version.  Since the `cmd` version is working for you, how about using `cmd.exe /c` to launch `gradlew.exe`?  Hopefully that works ...

Comment: your solution pointed me in the right direction :) finally! I had to change it a little bit tho, it's a .bat not an exe but the idea is the same:
 `wt -p windows cmd.exe /c d:\develop\config-server\gradlew bootrun`

Also it is not necessary to specify the path, Edit: I'm using my own profile in the 'p flag cause by default I'm using wsl

Comment: I still think wt should have a native way of doing it without relying on wsl or cmd

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Are you trying to change where the program starts?

You need to use `"startingDirectory"` to specify it, use colon `:` to separate the value and the key, use double quotes to enclose the values and add commas to the end of each line except if it's the last line in a section and square brackets `[]`.

And use either (forward) slashes `/` or double backslashes `\\` to delimit the directories.

For example:

```
{
    "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
    "colorScheme": "Campbell Powershell",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell",
    "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
    "startingDirectory" : "%Windir%/System32",
},
```

This makes PowerShell start in `C:\Windows\System32`

You need to edit the file located at path: `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Terminal_*\LocalState\settings.json`

---

I have pinned Windows Terminal to taskbar and run it by clicking its icon.
I use it to run all the consoles (`cmd`, `powershell`, `pwsh` and `python`), I think this is the easiest way to use Windows Terminal.

---

***Edit***:

For your particular problem, use this:

```
{
    "guid": "{9224ff83-e8dc-451f-8d81-524594fa5b0d}",
    "closeOnExit" : false,
    "commandline: "d:\develop\config-server\gradlew.exe bootrun",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Gradle",
}
```

---

You still need to set the profile instance first.

Then, to do what you intended, the ***RIGHT*** syntax is:

```
wt -p Gradle -d "d:\develop\config-server"
```

To run in a different folder (I.E. `%windir%\System32`), use:

Universal:

```
wt -p Gradle -d C:\Windows\System32
```

Command Prompt:

```
wt -p Gradle -d %windir%\System32
```

PowerShell:

```
wt -p Gradle -d $Env:windir\System32
```

Now if you want to run this in another folder:

```
wt -p Gradle -d C:\Path\to\folder
```

`-d` switch is used to specify starting directory, `-p` switch specifies what you want to run, did you read the page you linked?

Comment: no, I'm not trying to change the default starting directory, I just want to launch a command of a specific path in a new windows terminal

Comment: yeah but I would require creating a new profile everytime I need to execute something in a different folder with your approach

Comment: Wrong, you don't need to use a new profile, to execute in a different folder, change the directory after `-d` switch!

Comment: it's still not flexible, what if I need to execute something that isn't gradle? I would need a new profile

Comment: Yes, I think you need to create a profile for each new program you want to run, otherwise things will get messy...

Comment: Is this wt.exe / "windows terminal", a Windows 10 specific thing?

Comment: @barlop Yes Windows Terminal is Windows 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it requires WSL to be installed:

```
wt wsl --cd D:/develop/config-server ./gradlew bootrun
```